# The reputation badge shown in the summary, changes depending on the site.

Tags: bug, caching

Today I logged in to aviation.se to find that for a badge earned at stackexchange, the reputation change dropdown was showing me an aviation badge icon. So naturally I reported it at [meta.aviation](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/aviation-icon-showing-for-non-aviation-change-in-points), with the following screen shot:

[image]

Then I noticed the same thing happened when I shifted to travel.se:

[image]

So I believe this may be a larger issue with the network.