# Aviation icon showing for non-aviation change in points

Tags: bug, badges, achievements-dialog

This may be a larger issue, as I faced the same thing on travel.se; and reported it to the [SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281608/the-reputation-badge-shown-in-the-summary-changes-depending-on-the-site).

---

I'm not sure if this is a design issue or a caching problem, but today I received a notification for a rep change on stackoverflow, but with the icon for aviation:

[image]

Comment: It is not the aviation icon, but the aviation badge. I have seen this with the other sites as well. i.e. if I am on Puzzling.se I will see a "puzzle" badge for badges that I got on here and other sites.

Comment: Is it a bug? The badge shown is the one on which site you are on, regardless of the site where you earned the badge.

Comment: @Farhan how is that **not** a bug?

Comment: This certainly seems like a bug (the badge icon should probably match the iconography of the site where you *earned* the badge, not the one you're logged into -- or alternatively it should just be the generic circular badge icon). It's a network bug and not a site-specific one though, so I'm kicking it over to the Meta Meta...

Comment: @voretaq7 no, it's not a bug, and there's already a feature request here asking to change this behavior.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I disagree on it not being a bug (it is not the expected behavior - not meeting user expectations and displaying confusing symbology ***is*** a UI bug, and I can stack up an army of usability experts who would shout about it at great volume), and I'll go upvote the other issue for fixing it

Comment: @voretaq7 I'm not the one you have to convince. SE employee animuson also marked this as duplicate of the feature request, confirming SE itself see this as the expected design, and not as a bug. You can ping him and ask to reopen and mark it as [tag:status-bydesign] if you prefer. (Not sure he'll respond of course, but if you want it's worth trying.)